# Interpretation of dose-response relationship

Tags: regression, dose-response

In a regression analysis, how should I interpret the results if the main effect (exposed vs. unexposed) is null but a dose-response relationship exists? And vice versa if the main effect exists but there's a lack of a dose-response relationship?

Thank you!

Comment: There aren’t enough details here for us to give you a helpful answer. Please edit the question to say more about the experimental design, the data, and the modeling you did that provided the results you mention.